# create new pandas column based on if and else rule

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe and I want to create column e:

```
df
a    b   c   d
1    2   1   2
Nan Nan  3   1
Nan Nan Nan  5
4    5   0   2
```

I want create a new column based on this criteria:

1. The highest of column a vs column b.
2. If no value in column a and column b , then look column c
3. if no value in column c, then look column d.

```
df
a    b   c   d e
1    2   1   2 2
Nan Nan  3   1 3
Nan Nan Nan  5 5
4    5   0   2 5
```

my idea just until step number 2.

```
def e(x):
    if x['a'] >= x['b']:
        return x['a']
    elif x['a'] <= x['b']:
        return x['b']   
    else:
        x['c']

df['e'] = df.apply(e, axis=1)
```

Comment: What is output if changed second row `Nan Nan  3   1 5` to `Nan Nan  3   5` ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `pandas.DataFrame.bfill`:

```
df["e"] = df.bfill(1)[["a", "b"]].max(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c   d    e
0    1    2    1   2  2.0
1  NaN  NaN    3   1  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   5  5.0
3    4    5    0   2  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First get maximum `a, b` values and assign to `a` column, then back filling missing values and select first column for prioritize `c` and then `d` columns:

```
df['e'] = df.assign(a = df[['a','b']].max(axis=1)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
     a    b    c  d    e
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0  1  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  5  5.0
3  4.0  5.0  0.0  2  5.0
```

If want test only `a,b,c,d` columns and possible some another columns:

```
df['e'] = df[['a','b']].max(axis=1).fillna(df.c).fillna(df.d)
print (df)
     a    b    c  d    e
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0  5  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  5  5.0
3  4.0  5.0  0.0  2  5.0
```

If changed second row to `3,5` output is:

```
df['e'] = df.assign(a = df[['a','b']].max(axis=1)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
     a    b    c  d    e
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  3.0  5  3.0 <- changed d=5
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  5  5.0
3  4.0  5.0  0.0  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `np.where()`

```
df['e'] = df['d']
df['e'] = np.where((df['a'].isna()) & (df['b'].isna()) & (df['c'].notnull()), df['c'], df['e'])
df['e'] = np.where((df['a'].notnull()) & (df['b'].notnull()) & (df['a'] > df['b']), df['a'], df['e'])
df['e'] = np.where((df['a'].notnull()) & (df['b'].notnull()) & (df['b'] > df['a']), df['b'], df['e'])
df
```